# handling text files in R

Tags: r, file, text

I have 2 text files (tab delimited). The 1st file is the main file and the 2nd one is made from the 1st file. The main file looks like this:

> ```
> Rownames    IDs      SAM5511   SAM5566
> 1           EGS001    2        23 
> .     
> .
> 550         ESF012    3        76
> .
> .
> 1001        EFP125    4        55
> ```

And the 2nd one looks like this:

> ```
> X     log    p-val
> 1     4.5    0.001
> 550   2.3    0.021
> 1001  1.6    0.0005
> ```

I filtered the 1st file and changed the values to get the 2nd file so the number of rows in the 2nd file is less than the 1st one. As you see in the 1st file the 1st column is IDs but that of 2nd file is is the row names of 1st file (since it is filtered, all the rows are not included in the 2nd file). I want to make a text file like the 2nd file but it also has the corresponding IDs from the 1st file and it would be like this:

> ```
>  IDs      X      log     p-val
>  EGS001   1      4.5     0.001 
>  ESF012   550    2.3     0.021
>  EFP125   1001   1.6     0.0005
> ```

Comment: You may try `merge`, `match` etc.

Comment: there is no common column

Comment: What about the `Rownames` and `X` column?

Comment: rownames is not a column in the file

Comment: Your expected result showed the `X` rows  matching with the rownames of the first dataset.

Comment: If the second file is a subset of the first, you could have subset the columns that you needed.

Comment: If the Rownames column were for R rownames, then it would not be labeled "Rownames" (in fact it would bear no column label at all), so it's probably an ordinary column name.

Comment: Based on the data provided, I get the expected result by `merge(df1[1:2], df2, by.x='Rownames', by.y='X')`

Comment: @ BondedDust: I put it there to show how the structure is

Comment: @akbar How about creating a new column `Rownames` ie. `df1$Rownames <- 1:nrow(df1)` and then `merge`?

Comment: There is a parameter that one can set in `merge` to match on `rownames(df)`. Please read the help page. And please learn to post `dput(df)` next time so all this ambiguity can be avoided!

Answer (score 0):

You were advised to use "merge"  (but failed to post a reproducible example). If the actual R rownames were the valyes for which you are labeling "Rownames" then this might work:

```
 temp <- merge(df1,df2, by.x="row.names", by.y="IDs")
 final <- temp[ c("IDs", "X" ,"log", "p-val") ]
```

I suspect these are not really the column names (or the rownames), since if that were the case, then the dash in "p-val" would have been changed to a period by the default settings of `read.delim` or `read.table` and 'Rownames' would not have been recognized as such.

LEARN TO POST A REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE!